# Smart plug to measure AC energy (power) consumption that does not require a hub

Tags: power-supply, power, home-electronics, power-control, energy-efficient

I want to measure AC power consumption ***over time*** on a single outlet.  My multimeters will not do the job, as like nearly all multimeters, they display instantaneous values.

To accomplish this task, I believe I need to buy a socket power consumption meter.

These seem to come in 2 styles:

1. The first style is an integrated plug-in style.  The advantage to devices with this style is that they are "plug and play": they feature an integrated LCD screen that allows you to quickly see energy consumption over time.  The most famous brand is called "Kill-a-Watt".  The downsides of this style are that they are bulky and the screen is located at the outlet.  Perhaps one can use an extension cord to help with the latter issue... I'm not entirely sure if that is safe/recommended or if it impacts results.
2. The second style is a "smart plug".  These are tiny WiFi (or perhaps also Bluetooth) devices that plug into a receptacle and transmit their data to a computing device (typically a computer, tablet, or smartphone).

Please recommend a "smart plug" with the following features:

- Ability to measure AC energy consumption over time.  Measuring at least 24 hours is needed.
- Can send the data, in real-time, to an Android or Linux or Windows device (any are fine) via WiFi or Bluetooth (either is fine).
- Can turn on/off power to the receptacle from the connected (via WiFi/Bluetooth) computing device.
- ***IMPORTANT:*** Does *not* require a hub like Alexa, Echo, or Google Home.
- ***IMPORTANT:*** Does *not* require any internet access.

Comment: I've purchased in the past a product from BN_Link via Amazon which appears to cover the entire list you provided. Unfortunately, these devices were older versions and the current set lack the AC features. I contacted the manufacturer and was told supply chain problems resulted in the loss of those features.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Thanks Fred.  What's the name/ID of the product?  Perhaps I can find an old one from somewhere.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07CX5KLXN/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

This link was what I used to place a second order, which was missing the energy consumption feature. This order and the following one had no text referencing the feature, making it all the more difficult to locate such a useful product.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Thank you for the reference.  That's quite disappointing regarding the lack of text referencing the feature.  With the model number not changing an the text missing from their old and new versions finding the correct unit will be link finding a needle in a haystack (and having to try each piece of hay to check whether or not it is the needle!).

Comment: Here's a thought, I know you don't want a hub, but here's something to think about a software product called "Home Assistant" will generate graphs and more for any time period or etc.  Now usually people run it on a raspberry pi, but everything is local on your network.  Yes, it is convenient to have internet access periodically for software updates, but not required.

Answer (score 2):

Our discussion in the comments caused me to realize that the search terms "smart plug with power monitoring" may provide useful results. The first link that appeared, for an [Amazon product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09YV2L3MN) appears to cover all the bases. Image below from linked site.

No hub required. No internet required (but optional). Bluetooth™ and Wifi compatible.

Power monitoring!

[image: power monitoring image]

Comment: That looks very promising... Thank you!  At first, I thought the price was unreasonable, and then I saw it was for a 4-pack.  I was thinking of searching for a 1-pack or a 2-pack, but actually, a 4-pack could be quite nice, especially since 1 app would be used to control each of them.  Might even consider dedicating an old Android device sitting in a drawer as a remote control if the companion Android app supports older versions of Android.

Comment: I have done exactly that with one of the non-power monitoring modules. My hobby room has a few objects that don't have to be operating constantly and it's convenient to start/stop from other rooms, but also from the formerly-idle 'droid phone stuck to a nearby surface.